# how to stop the setTimeout function in javascript in this case?

Tags: javascript, settimeout

I'm trying to build a reaction timer using js only but whenever i earlyClick, my setTimeout doest seem to work. If i don't click early, the problem doesn't occur. Just need to fix the earlyClick issue. Please help!

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Reflex Calculator</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="reflexCalculator.css">
</head>
<body>

<div id="container">

    <h1  id="seconds"></h1>
    <h2 style="text-align: center;" id="text">Click to begin.</h2>

</div>

<script type="text/javascript">

var startTime, endTime, difference;
    /*sets delay amount*/

    var randomNumberBetween2and19 = Math.floor(Math.random() * 20)+2;
    function delay1(){
        var seconds=randomNumberBetween2and19/5;
        return seconds;
    }
    var time=delay1().toFixed(3);
    /*program begins*/
    document.getElementById("container").onclick=function(){
    firstClick();}
    /*Reflex timer starts with initial color green!*/
    function firstClick(){

       document.getElementById("container").style.background="red";/*green*/
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="wait till blue";
```

this is where the main problem occurs but i don't know how to fix it i just want, if i click early, run earlyClick function and stop setTimeout

```
        if(document.getElementById("container").clicked) earlyClick();


        else setTimeout(calculateReflex, time*1000);
    }
    function earlyClick(){
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="Too Early! You have to 
        start over again.";
        document.getElementById("container").style.background="yellow";
        //document.getElementById("container").onclick=function(){start();} 
        document.getElementById("container").onclick=function()
    {lastClick();}
    }
    /*function where i use delay to calculate reflex*/
    function calculateReflex(){
        startTime=Date.now();
        document.getElementById("container").style.background="blue";
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="CLICK!";
        document.getElementById("container").onclick=function(){result();}      
    }
    function result(){
        endTime=Date.now();
        difference=endTime-startTime;
        document.getElementById("container").style.background="#fc3";
        document.getElementById("text").innerHTML="your reflex is 
 "+difference/1000+"s"+"<br/>Click to restart";
        document.getElementById("container").onclick=function()
 {lastClick();}
    }
    /*For reload*/
    function lastClick(){
        window.location.reload();
    }

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: There's the one and only documented way to [stop the timeout](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WindowOrWorkerGlobalScope/clearTimeout).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this

```
var myVar = setTimeout(function, milliseconds);
clearTimeout(myVar);
```

Answer (score 0):

to stop a setTimeout you need to store the timeout identifier when creating a timeout:
`var timeoutId = setTimeout(...);`
then use `clearTimeout(timeoutId)` to clear the timeout before it has trigerred.